# py2exe and win32com with excel

Tags: py2exe, win32com

I've made a script that that changes the color in an excel file. Herefor I use:
    import win32com.client as win32
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

Now I want to make an exe file with py2exe. It gives a Key error <000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046>. I know the problem is with the win32com.client, but I can not solve it.

Has anybody an idea?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer- this is mostly a guess:

Try using win32.Dispatch or win32.DispatchEx. EnsureDispatch actually creates a .py file with a class representing the COM object requested and returns that, so it might interact oddly with the py2exe functionality.

I don't know how COM works below the python wrapper, but I'd guess something along the lines of that py2exe might be locking in the COM object data set in the gencache makepy file instead of allowing it to be dynamically generated if in changes within the runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had just solved this problem.
if you want use win32 of com service, first you should ensure that the com service has already running,to check this by executing:
    "dcomcnfg" in command line, if com service of excel has start correctly ,you should see "Microsoft Excel Application" in the dcom service list like this:
    [the correct result should like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7KXp.png)
   if "Microsoft Excel Application" not in the list, you can solve this problem by [Microsoft Excel or Microsoft Word does not appear in DCOM Configuration snap-in](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-or-microsoft-word-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in/)